# Differences between BigQuery and Google Analytics outputs

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

Am trying to get the count of distinct authorized customers from both Bigquery and Google Analytics, but I see a huge difference. 
BigQuery gives me 15% less counts compared to GA. Is this something to do with unnesting or any other issues?

bigquery:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  customDimensionByIndex(indx INT64,
    arr ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64,
    value STRING>>) AS ( (
    SELECT
      x.value
    FROM
      UNNEST(arr) x
    WHERE
      indx=x.index) );

SELECT
  auth,
  COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    customDimensionByIndex(2,
      hit.customDimensions) AS auth
  FROM
    `test-apis2.94566232234.ga_sessions_20180422`,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hit )
GROUP BY 1
```

This query gives me
Authorized - TRUE: *76,649

GA gives me *50,833

But I see very close numbers for "FALSE".

Am trying to find why there is huge difference for "TRUE". Appreciate any little help.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There isn't enough information here for anyone to be able to help. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). How is it possible for someone to tell whether there is an unnesting issue without seeing the query you are using?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I apologize for not making things clear. I did edit the question. Please let me know your thoughts on this

Comment: Are we talking about fullVisitorId here? You are flattening the table to hit scope - do you have "auth" in GA as a hit-scoped dimension as well?

Comment: Are you using Legacy or Standard SQL? COUNT(DISTINCT) in Legacy SQL does not return the exact count. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#countdistinct